# Sockect Direct Protocol vs FTP Java Library

Tags: java-7, apache-commons-net, java, infiniband, ofed

Currently I am using [**Apache's Commons Net library**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) for transferring some application files(2KB to 200MB) from one AIX server to another through FTP protocol. I came to know that there is an another protocol exists i.e **SDP(Socket Direct Protocol)** through **Infiniband** or **OFED (OpenFabrics Enterprise Distribution)** which provides a high performance, low latency, reliable switch fabric to serve as a scalable I/O interconnect. Java 7 and above provide [**Java API for SDP**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sdp/sockets/) for this protocol.

Can anyone elaborate on the significance and challenges in shifting from FTP to SDP.

Comment: ny other ideaa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transferring large files using SDP should provide higher throughput with less CPU utilization. When transferring the smaller files you might get lower latency.

I think the main challenge with SDP is that the wire protocol is different, so you have to change both your client and your server to use SDP.

Comment: I have files between 2KB to 200MB. Can I go for SDP for all sized file?